# Killing a tunnel and establishing a tunnel through SSH

Tags: python, child-process, ssh

I have two functions right now:

```
TUNNEL_COMMAND = "ssh -L 27017:localhost:27017 username@ip -f -N"

def kill_tunnel():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    for line in out.splitlines():
        if TUNNEL_COMMAND in line:
            pid = int(line.split()[1])
            print "killing pid", pid 
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)

def connect_tunnel():
    subprocess.Popen(TUNNEL_COMMAND)
```

`connect_tunnel()` establishes the connection, which I am ok with, but `kill_tunnel()` looks very ugly. Is there a better way to find the PID of a process based off the command?

Comment: would not be easier to use [`paramiko`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294919/port-forwarding-with-paramiko) then inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Jakuje ah... well if I've known about this haha.. I think I should refactor my code a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `pgrep` with the `-f` option to match the whole command line so that we can match the desired process precisely?

For example, in you case something like:

```
pgrep -f 'ssh.*27017:localhost:27017'
```

might give the accurate PID. If you desire, you can modify it to make it more robust.

Implementing this in Python:

```py
import subprocess
import os
import signal

def kill_tunnel():
    try:
        tunnel_pid = subprocess.check_output(['pgrep', '-f', 'ssh.*27017:localhost:27017'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return 'No Such Process'
    os.kill(tunnel_pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```